# Evaluate dice rolling notation strings

Tags: language-agnostic, dice, expression-evaluation

### Rules

Write a function that accepts string as a parameter, returning
evaluated value of expression in [dice notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation), 
including addition and multiplication.

To clear the things up, here comes EBNF definition of legal expressions:

```
roll ::= [positive integer], "d", positive integer
entity ::= roll | positive number
expression ::= entity { [, whitespace], "+"|"*"[, whitespace], entity }
```

Example inputs:

- "3d6 + 12"
- "4*d12 + 3"
- "d100"

Using **eval** functions, or similar, is not forbidden, but I encourage
to solving without using these. Re-entrancy is welcome.

I cannot provide test-cases, as output should be random ;).

Format your answers' titles: language, n characters (important notes — no eval, etc.)

---

My **ruby** solution, <del>92</del> 81 characters, using eval:

```
def f s
eval s.gsub(/(\d+)?d(\d+)/i){eval"a+=rand $2.to_i;"*a=($1||1).to_i}
end
```

Another **ruby** solution, not shorter (92 characters), but I find it interesting — it still uses eval but this time in quite creative way.

```
class Fixnum
def**b
eval"a+=rand b;"*a=self
end
end
def f s
eval s.gsub(/d/,'**')
end
```

Comment: What exactly would differentiate »4*d12« from »4d12«? Am I missing something?

Comment: I have an expression evaluator that solves this including variables and the d% notation. But it's not a hole in one. Maybe I post the code tonight.

Comment: @Johannes: they are mostly equal. But d12 = short for 1d12 so 4*d12 = 4*1d12.

Comment: By the way does it have to evaluate 2d2d6 and if so, how is it interpreted 2d(2d6) or (2d2)d6.

Comment: @Johannes, I suppose it's possible that 4*d12 means roll one d12 and multiply the result by 4 (as opposed to rolling the d12 4 separate times and adding up the results).  This sounds like someone's homework anyway and the original poster should post some code of their own to show they've at least made an effort.

Comment: @Gamecat, 2d2d6 is just illegal.

Comment: @Onorio Catenacci, it is not homework, and I will post my solution. I'm trying to make it as brief as possible right now.

Comment: Sounds more like homework-avoidance than homework ;-)

Comment: @onebyone, it's sad how close to the truth are you ;)

Comment: 2d2d6 does have a useful meaning, which is (2-4)d6, and I have seen games that asked for a random number of dice to be rolled.  2d(2d6) doesn't make sense to me.  Not that it needs to be in the problem.

Comment: Onorio is right - standard RPG notation would be that 4d12 means d12 + d12 + d12 + d12, but 4*d12 would be 4 * d12.

Comment: RPG?  Who said anything about RPGs?!  I'm sure this is for something totally unrelated.  Make a check against Wisdom to see if you believe me.

Comment: Am I seeing this right and the dice rolls should be summed up in any case? Currently I am only adding the rolls together if either factor or addend are given.

Comment: @Johannes: you will sum if addend is given or if rolling multiple dice.

Comment: The 4*d12 puzzles me.  I'm used to seeing this as d12x4, although if you are doing it in code you almost certainly should really use d45+3.

Comment: @David--2d(2d6) actually could be parsed.  Roll 2d6.  Now take two rolls of the die you got from the 2d6.

Comment: @Beska--I think you're referring to D&D.  D&D is a type of RPG!

Comment: Your latest change ("a=$1.to_i||1") won't work. $1 can be nil, and nil.to_i == 0, not nil. In other words, "d12" will give a result of 0 or nil (not sure which) every time.

Comment: @Samir Talwar, thanks for pointing this out. Fixed.

Comment: By the way, there is a special case where d% maps d100. You shouldn't forget that.

Comment: @samuil Did you mean "integer" where you said "number" ? Pi is a positive "number" :)   Also unit tests can still be written and give some meaning. e.g. 3d6+2 must give a result in range 5-20.

Comment: @nslntmnx quite a digger you are — it's been 8 years already :) Integer makes more sense, sure. When it comes to the tests — either you should verify that rand is being called with proper arguments correct number of times, or you need to verify that results have correct distribution, which isn't simple task. Verifying range would be only the very beginning :)

Comment: @samuil 8 years. Wow.  But I at least still found it interesting.  Yes, distribution would be another worthy test.  Perhaps something could be done with mocking the rand, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 13):

C# class.  It evaluates recursively for addition and multiplication, left-to-right for chained die rolls

**Edits:**

- Removed `.Replace(" ","")` on each call
- Added `.Trim()` on `int.TryParse` instead
- All work is now done in single method
- If die face count is not specified, assumes 6 (see Wiki article)
- Refactored redundant call to parse left side of "d"
- Refactored unnecessary `if` statement

Minified: (411 bytes)

```
class D{Random r=new Random();public int R(string s){int t=0;var a=s.Split('+');if(a.Count()>1)foreach(var b in a)t+=R(b);else{var m=a[0].Split('*');if(m.Count()>1){t=1;foreach(var n in m)t*=R(n);}else{var d=m[0].Split('d');if(!int.TryParse(d[0].Trim(),out t))t=0;int f;for(int i=1;i<d.Count();i++){if(!int.TryParse(d[i].Trim(),out f))f=6;int u=0;for(int j=0;j<(t== 0?1:t);j++)u+=r.Next(1,f);t+=u;}}}return t;}}
```

Expanded form:

```
    class D
    {
        /// <summary>Our Random object.  Make it a first-class citizen so that it produces truly *random* results</summary>
        Random r = new Random();

        /// <summary>Roll</summary>
        /// <param name="s">string to be evaluated</param>
        /// <returns>result of evaluated string</returns>
        public int R(string s)
        {
            int t = 0;

            // Addition is lowest order of precedence
            var a = s.Split('+');

            // Add results of each group
            if (a.Count() > 1)
                foreach (var b in a)
                    t += R(b);
            else
            {
                // Multiplication is next order of precedence
                var m = a[0].Split('*');

                // Multiply results of each group
                if (m.Count() > 1)
                {
                    t = 1; // So that we don't zero-out our results...

                    foreach (var n in m)
                        t *= R(n);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Die definition is our highest order of precedence
                    var d = m[0].Split('d');

                    // This operand will be our die count, static digits, or else something we don't understand
                    if (!int.TryParse(d[0].Trim(), out t))
                        t = 0;

                    int f;

                    // Multiple definitions ("2d6d8") iterate through left-to-right: (2d6)d8
                    for (int i = 1; i < d.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        // If we don't have a right side (face count), assume 6
                        if (!int.TryParse(d[i].Trim(), out f))
                            f = 6;

                        int u = 0;

                        // If we don't have a die count, use 1
                        for (int j = 0; j < (t == 0 ? 1 : t); j++)
                            u += r.Next(1, f);

                        t += u;
                    }
                }
            }

            return t;
        }
    }
```

Test cases:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new List<string>();
        t.Add("2d6");
        t.Add("2d6d6");
        t.Add("2d8d6 + 4d12*3d20");
        t.Add("4d12");
        t.Add("4*d12");
        t.Add("4d"); // Rolls 4 d6

        D d = new D();
        foreach (var s in t)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", d.R(s), s));
    }
```

Comment: The real problem space includes negatives as well as positives.

Comment: @Hardwareguy, purpose of code golfs is not readability at all.

Comment: @Loren: Yes, but in this case the "problem statement" was listed as only addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/)

With cobbal's help, squeeze everything into 93 characters.

```
$ jconsole
   e=:".@([`('%'"_)@.(=&'/')"0@,)@:(3 :'":(1".r{.y)([:+/>:@?@$) ::(y&[)0".}.y}.~r=.y i.''d'''@>)@;:

   e '3d6 + 12'
20
   e 10$,:'3d6 + 12'
19 23 20 26 24 20 20 20 24 27
   e 10$,:'4*d12 + 3'
28 52 56 16 52 52 52 36 44 56
   e 10$,:'d100'
51 51 79 58 22 47 95 6 5 64
```

Comment: try replacing the inside of f with ": (1 ". r {. y) d :: (y&[) 0 ". }. y }.~ r =. y i. 'd'

Comment: Thanks!  We need more J users around this section.  When there are 50,000 ways to solve a problem, it really helps to have other people looking at alternates :)

Comment: it's a bit of a daunting language, but it's amazing what you can do with it. Certainly changes how you think about many problems

Answer (score 4):

**JavaScript** solution, 340 chars when compressed (no eval, supports prefixed multiplicator and suffixed addition):

```
function comp (s, m, n, f, a) {
    m = parseInt( m );
    if( isNaN( m ) ) m = 1;
    n = parseInt( n );
    if( isNaN( n ) ) n = 1;
    f = parseInt( f );
    a = typeof(a) == 'string' ? parseInt( a.replace(/\s/g, '') ) : 0;
    if( isNaN( a ) ) a = 0;
    var r = 0;
    for( var i=0; i<n; i++ )
        r += Math.floor( Math.random() * f );
    return r * m + a;
};
function parse( de ) {
    return comp.apply( this, de.match(/(?:(\d+)\s*\*\s*)?(\d*)d(\d+)(?:\s*([\+\-]\s*\d+))?/i) );
}
```

Test code:

```
var test = ["3d6 + 12", "4*d12 + 3", "d100"];
for(var i in test)
    alert( test[i] + ": " + parse(test[i]) );
```

Compressed version (pretty sure you can do shorter):

```
function c(s,m,n,f,a){m=parseInt(m);if(isNaN(m))m=1;n=parseInt(n);if(isNaN(n))n=1;f=parseInt(f);a=typeof(a)=='string'?parseInt(a.replace(/\s/g,'')):0;if(isNaN(a))a=0;var r=0;for(var i=0;i<n;i++)r+=Math.floor(Math.random()*f);return r*m+a;};function p(d){return c.apply(this,d.match(/(?:(\d+)\s*\*\s*)?(\d*)d(\d+)(?:\s*([\+\-]\s*\d+))?/i));}
```

Answer (score 4):

**perl** eval version, 72 chars

```
sub e{$_=pop;s/(\d+)?d(\d+)/\$a/i;$a+=1+int rand$2-1for 0...$1-1;eval$_}
```

runs like

```
print e("4*d12+3"),"\n";
```

Based on the ruby solution, can only run once(you should `undef $a` between runs).

shorter version, 68 chars, funky (0 based) dice

```
sub e{$_=pop;s/(\d+)?d(\d+)/\$a/i;$a+=int rand$2for 0...$1-1;eval$_}
```

**EDIT**

perl 5.8.8 didn't like the previous version, here's a 73 char version that works

```
sub e{$_=pop;s/(\d+)?d(\d+)/\$a/i;$a+=1+int rand$2-1for 1...$1||1;eval$_}
```

70 char version supporting multiple rolls

```
sub e{$_=pop;s/(\d*)d(\d+)/$a=$1||1;$a+=int rand$a*$2-($a-1)/ieg;eval}
```

Comment: Rules did not mention re-entrancy, so your solution is correct :)

Comment: Some shortening tips - use '..' insetead of '...', use '(\d*)' instead of '(\d+)?', and if eval() is given no arguments it defaults to $_

Answer (score 4):

python, 197 chars in obscured version.

Readable version: 369 chars. No eval, straight forward parsing.

```
import random
def dice(s):
    return sum(term(x) for x in s.split('+'))
def term(t):
    p = t.split('*')
    return factor(p[0]) if len(p)==1 else factor(p[0])*factor(p[1])
def factor(f):
    p = f.split('d')
    if len(p)==1:
        return int(f)
    return sum(random.randint(1, int(g[1]) if g[1] else 6) for \
               i in range(int(g[0]) if g[0] else 1))
```

compressed version: 258 chars, single character names, abused conditional expressions, shortcut in logical expression:

```
import random
def d(s):
 return sum(t(x.split('*')) for x in s.split('+'))
def t(p):
 return f(p[0])*f(p[1]) if p[1:] else f(p[0])
def f(s):
 g = s.split('d')
 return sum(random.randint(1, int(g[1] or 6)) for i in range(int(g[0] or 1))) if g[1:] else int(s)
```

obscured version: 216 chars, using reduce, map heavily to avoid "def", "return".

```
import random
def d(s):
 return sum(map(lambda t:reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,map(lambda f:reduce(lambda x,y:sum(random.randint(1,int(y or 6)) for i in range(int(x or 1))), f.split('d')+[1]),t.split('*')),1),s.split('+')))
```

Last version: 197 chars, folded in @Brain's comments, added testing runs.

```
import random
R=reduce;D=lambda s:sum(map(lambda t:R(int.__mul__,map(lambda f:R(lambda x,y:sum(random.randint(1,int(y or 6))for i in[0]*int(x or 1)),f.split('d')+[1]),t.split('*'))),s.split('+')))
```

Tests:

```
>>> for dice_expr in ["3d6 + 12", "4*d12 + 3","3d+12", "43d29d16d21*9+d7d9*91+2*d24*7"]: print dice_expr, ": ", list(D(dice_expr) for i in range(10))
... 
3d6 + 12 :  [22, 21, 22, 27, 21, 22, 25, 19, 22, 25]
4*d12 + 3 :  [7, 39, 23, 35, 23, 23, 35, 27, 23, 7]
3d+12 :  [16, 25, 21, 25, 20, 18, 27, 18, 27, 25]
43d29d16d21*9+d7d9*91+2*d24*7 :  [571338, 550124, 539370, 578099, 496948, 525259, 527563, 546459, 615556, 588495]
```

This solution can't handle whitespaces without adjacent digits. so "43d29d16d21*9+d7d9*91+2*d24*7" will work, but "43d29d16d21*9 + d7d9*91 + 2*d24*7" will not, due to the second space (between "+" and "d"). It can be corrected by first removing whitespaces from s, but this will make the code longer than 200 chars, so I'll keep the bug.

Comment: I don't think this can handle prefixes before a 'd'. Correct me if I'm wrong, however.

Comment: You can get it down to 202 with a few microoptimisations: Using d=lambda s: avoids needing "return", saving 5 chars.  Binding reduce to a single character saves 1 more, and you can change range(int(x or 1)) to [0]*int(x or 1) for another 4.  Line 2 becomes:  "R=reduce;d=lambda s:sum(map(lambda t:R(lambda x,y:x*y,map(lambda f:R(lambda x,y:sum(random.randint(1,int(y or 6))for i in[0]*int(x or 1)),f.split('d')+[1]),t.split('*')),1),s.split('+')))"

Comment: One more improvement: "lambda x,y:x*y" can be changed to "int.__mul__", bringing you below the 200 mark.

Comment: @Brain: Thanks. I like the use of re in your solution, hope I've come to that idea.
@Noldorin: Do you mean the cases like "3d6"? If so, it's handled, if not, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 4):

**Clojure, 854 characters as is, 412 shrunk**

Just run "(roll-dice "*input-string*")".

```
(defn roll-dice
  [string]
  (let [parts (. (. (. string replace "-" "+-") replaceAll "\\s" "") split "\\+")
        dice-func (fn [d-notation]
                    (let [bits (. d-notation split "d")]
                      (if (= 1 (count bits))
                        (Integer/parseInt (first bits))  ; Just a number, like 12
                        (if (zero? (count (first bits)))
                          (inc (rand-int (Integer/parseInt (second bits))))  ; Just d100 or some such
                          (if (. (first bits) contains "*")
                            (* (Integer/parseInt (. (first bits) replace "*" ""))
                                (inc (rand-int (Integer/parseInt (second bits)))))
                            (reduce +
                              (map #(+ 1 %)
                                    (map rand-int
                                        (repeat
                                          (Integer/parseInt (first bits))
                                          (Integer/parseInt (second bits)))))))))))]      
    (reduce + (map dice-func parts))))
```

To shrink, I made variables 1 letter, moved the (first bits)/(second bits) into variables, made dice-func an anonymous function, made a wrapper for Integer.parseInt called 'i', and stripped out comments and extra whitespace.

This should work on anything valid, with or without whitespace. Just don't go asking it for "15dROBERT", it will throw an exception.

They way it works is by splitting up the string into dice (that's the 3rd line, the let). So "5d6+2*d4-17" becomes "5d6","2*d4","-17".

Each of those is then processed by the function dice-func, and the results are added up (this is the map/reduce on the last line)

Dice-func takes a little dice string (such a "5d6") and splits it on the "d". If there is only one part left, it was a simple number (6, -17, etc).

If the first part contains a *, we multiply that number by a random interger, 1 to (number after d), inclusive.

If the first part doesn't contain a *, we take first number random rolls (just like previous line) and add them up (this is the map/reduce in the middle).

This was fun little challenge.

Answer (score 4):

**Python** 124 chars with eval, 154 without.

Just to show python doesn't *have* to be readable, here's a 124 character solution, with a similar eval-based approach to the original:

```
import random,re
f=lambda s:eval(re.sub(r'(\d*)d(\d+)',lambda m:int(m.group(1)or 1)*('+random.randint(1,%s)'%m.group(2)),s))
```

[Edit]  And here's a 154 character one without eval:

```
import random,re
f=lambda s:sum(int(c or 0)+sum(random.randint(1,int(b))for i in[0]*int(a or 1))for a,b,c in re.findall(r'(\d*)d(\d+)(\s*[+-]\s*\d+)?',s))
```

Note: both will work for inputs like "2d6 + 1d3 + 5" but don't support more advanced variants like "2d3d6" or negative dice ("1d6-4" is OK, but "1d6-2d4" isn't) (You can shave off 2 characters to not support negative numbers at all in the second one instead)

Answer (score 4):

### F# (*no* eval and *no* regex)

**233 characters**

This solution should be fully generic, in that it can handle just about any string you throw at it, even something crazy such as:

> 43d29d16d21*9 + d7d9*91 + 2*d24*7

Need to define this globally:

```
let r = new System.Random()
```

Fully obfuscated version:

```
let f(s:string)=let g d o i p (t:string)=t.Split([|d|])|>Array.fold(fun s x->o s (p x))i in g '+'(+)0(g '*' (*) 1 (fun s->let b=ref true in g 'd'(+)1(fun t->if !b then b:=false;(if t.Trim()=""then 1 else int t)else r.Next(int t))s))s
```

Readable version:

```
let f (s:string) =
    let g d o i p (t:string) =
        t.Split([|d|]) |> Array.fold (fun s x -> o s (p x)) i
    g '+' (+) 0 (g '*' (*) 1 (fun s ->
                                        let b = ref true
                                        g 'd' (+) 1 (fun t ->
                                        if !b then b := false; (if t.Trim() = "" then 1 else int t)
                                        else r.Next(int t)) s)) s
```

I'm challenging someone to beat this solution (in any language) *without* using `eval` or regular expressions. I think it's likely to be possible, but I am interested in seeing the approach still.

Answer (score 3):

**perl**, no evals, 144 chars, works multiple times, supports multiple dice rolls

```
sub e{($c=pop)=~y/+* /PT/d;$b='(\d+)';map{$a=0while$c=~s!$b?$_$b!$d=$1||1;$a+=1+int rand$2for 1..$d;$e=$2;/d/?$a:/P/?$d+$e:$d*$e!e}qw(d T P);$c}
```

Expanded version, with comments

```
sub f {
    ($c = pop); #assign first function argument to $c
    $c =~ tr/+* /PT/d;  #replace + and * so we won't have to escape them later.
                        #also remove spaces
    #for each of 'd','T' and 'P', assign to $_ and run the following
    map {
        #repeatedly replace in $c the first instance of <number> <operator> <number> with
        #the result of the code in second part of regex, capturing both numbers and
        #setting $a to zero after every iteration
        $a=0 while $c =~ s[(\d+)?$_(\d+)][
            $d = $1 || 1;   #save first parameter (or 1 if not defined) as later regex 
                            #will overwrite it
            #roll $d dice, sum in $a
            for (1..$d)
            {
                $a += 1 + int rand $2;
            }
            $e = $2;        #save second parameter, following regexes will overwrite
            #Code blocks return the value of their last statement
            if (/d/)
            {
                $a; #calculated dice throw
            }
            elsif (/P/)
            {
                $d + $e;
            }
            else
            {
                $d * $e;
            }
        ]e;
    } qw(d T P);
    return $c;
}
```

**EDIT** cleaned up, updated explanation to latest version

Comment: Could you provide deobfuscated version?

Comment: Some attempt at explanation added. hopefully makes some sense

Comment: Thanks for that. When I understand your algorithm, I have one remark — you can't calculate result of multiple dice roll with single rand call, as it will have uniform distribution instead of near-Gaussian.

Comment: Added a version with non uniform dice, now 146 chars instead of 145

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby**, 166 characters, no `eval`

In my opinion quite elegant ;).

```
def g s,o=%w{\+ \* d}
o[a=0]?s[/#{p=o.pop}/]?g(s.sub(/(\d+)?\s*(#{p})\s*(\d+)/i){c=$3.to_i
o[1]?($1||1).to_i.times{a+=rand c}+a:$1.to_i.send($2,c)},o<<p):g(s,o):s
end
```

Deobfuscated version + comments:

```
def evaluate(string, opers = ["\\+","\\*","d"])
  if opers.empty?
    string
  else
    if string.scan(opers.last[/.$/]).empty? # check if string contains last element of opers array

      # Proceed to next operator from opers array.

      opers.pop
      evaluate(string, opers)

    else # string contains that character...

      # This is hard to deobfuscate. It substitutes subexpression with highest priority with
      # its value (e.g. chooses random value for XdY, or counts value of N+M or N*M), and
      # calls recursively evaluate with substituted string.

      evaluate(string.sub(/(\d+)?\s*(#{opers.last})\s*(\d+)/i) { a,c=0,$3.to_i; ($2 == 'd') ? ($1||1).to_i.times{a+=rand c}+a : $1.to_i.send($2,c) }, opers)

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python**, 452 bytes in the compressed version

I'm not sure if this is cool, ugly, or plain stupid, but it was fun writing it.

What we do is as follows: We use regexes (which is usually not the right tool for this kind of thing) to convert the dice notation string into a list of commands in a small, stack-based language. This language has four commands:

- `mul` multiplies the top two numbers on the stack and pushes the result
- `add` adds the top two numbers on the stack and pushes the result
- `roll` pops the dice size from the stack, then the count, rolls a size-sided dice count times and pushes the result
- a number just pushes itself onto the stack

This command list is then evaluated.

```
import re, random

def dice_eval(s):
    s = s.replace(" ","")
    s = re.sub(r"(\d+|[d+*])",r"\1 ",s) #seperate tokens by spaces
    s = re.sub(r"(^|[+*] )d",r"\g<1>1 d",s) #e.g. change d 6 to 1 d 6
    while "*" in s:
        s = re.sub(r"([^+]+) \* ([^+]+)",r"\1 \2mul ",s,1)
    while "+" in s:
        s = re.sub(r"(.+) \+ (.+)",r"\1 \2add ",s,1)
    s = re.sub(r"d (\d+) ",r"\1 roll ",s)

    stack = []

    for token in s.split():
        if token == "mul":
            stack.append(stack.pop() * stack.pop())
        elif token == "add":
            stack.append(stack.pop() + stack.pop())
        elif token == "roll":
            v = 0
            dice = stack.pop()
            for i in xrange(stack.pop()):
                v += random.randint(1,dice)
            stack.append(v)
        elif token.isdigit():
            stack.append(int(token))
        else:
            raise ValueError

    assert len(stack) == 1

    return stack.pop() 

print dice_eval("2*d12+3d20*3+d6")
```

By the way (this was discussed in the question comments), this implementation will allow strings like `"2d3d6"`, understanding this as "roll a d3 twice, then roll a d6 as many times as the result of the two rolls."

Also, although there is some error checking, it still expects a valid input. Passing "*4" for example will result in an infinite loop.

Here is the compressed version (not pretty):

```
import re, random
r=re.sub
def e(s):
 s=r(" ","",s)
 s=r(r"(\d+|[d+*])",r"\1 ",s)
 s=r(r"(^|[+*] )d",r"\g<1>1 d",s)
 while"*"in s:s=r(r"([^+]+) \* ([^+]+)",r"\1 \2M ",s)
 while"+"in s:s=r(r"(.+) \+ (.+)",r"\1 \2A ",s)
 s=r(r"d (\d+)",r"\1 R",s)
 t=[]
 a=t.append
 p=t.pop
 for k in s.split():
  if k=="M":a(p()*p())
  elif k=="A":a(p()+p())
  elif k=="R":
   v=0
   d=p()
   for i in [[]]*p():v+=random.randint(1,d)
   a(v)
  else:a(int(k))
 return p()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby, 87 characters, uses `eval`**

Here's my Ruby solution, partially based on the OP's. It's five characters shorter and only uses `eval` once.

```
def f s
eval s.gsub(/(\d+)?[dD](\d+)/){n=$1?$1.to_i: 1;n.times{n+=rand $2.to_i};n}
end
```

A readable version of the code:

```
def f s
    eval (s.gsub /(\d+)?[dD](\d+)/ do
        n = $1 ? $1.to_i : 1
        n.times { n += rand $2.to_i }
        n
    end)
end
```

Comment: Good point about not using .nil?, but double eval version is shorter anyway ;)

Comment: Can be shortened by another 2 chars by changing the regex to /(\d+)?d(\d+)/i

Answer (score 1):

**JAVASCRIPT**, 1399 chars, no eval

old post, i know. but i try to contribute

```
Roll = window.Roll || {};

Roll.range = function (str) {
    var rng_min, rng_max, str_split,
        delta, value;

    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    str_split = str.split("-");
    rng_min = str_split[0];
    rng_max = str_split[1];

    rng_min = parseInt(rng_min) || 0;
    rng_max = Math.max(parseInt(rng_max), rng_min) || rng_min;

    delta = (rng_max - rng_min + 1);

    value = Math.random() * delta;
    value = parseInt(value);

    return value + rng_min;
};

Roll.rollStr = function (str) {
    var check,
        qta, max, dice, mod_opts, mod,
        rng_min, rng_max,
        rolls = [], value = 0;

    str = str.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    check = str.match(/(?:^[-+]?(\d+)?(?:\/(\d+))?[dD](\d+)(?:([-+])(\d+)\b)?$|^(\d+)\-(\d+)$)/);

    if (check == null) {return "ERROR"}
    qta = check[1];
    max = check[2];
    dice = check[3];
    mod_opts = check[4];
    mod = check[5];
    rng_min = check[6];
    rng_max = check[7];
    check = check[0];

    if (rng_min && rng_max) {return Roll.range(str)}

    dice = parseInt(dice);
    mod_opts = mod_opts || "";
    mod = parseInt(mod) || 0;
    qta = parseInt(qta) || 1;
    max = Math.max(parseInt(max), qta) || qta;

    for (var val; max--;) {
        val = Math.random() * dice;
        val = Math.floor(val) + 1;
        rolls.push(val);
    }

    if (max != qta) {
        rolls.sort(function (a, b) {return a < b});
        rolls.unshift(rolls.splice(0, qta));
    }

    while (rolls[0][0]) {value += rolls[0].shift();}

    if (mod_opts == "-") {value -= mod;}
    else {value += mod;}

    return value
};

if (!window.diceRoll) {window.diceRoll= Roll.rollStr;}
```

it's a single dice roll, like "2d8+2" or "4-18" "3/4d6" (best 3 of 4 d6)

```
diceRoll("2d8+2"); 
diceRoll("4-18");
diceRoll("3/4d6");
```

to check cumulative rolls, better loop on matched result ove rthe input string like

```
r = "2d8+2+3/4d6"
r.match(/([-+])?(\d+)?(?:\/(\d+))?[dD](\d+)(?:([-+])(\d+)\b)?/g);
// => ["2d8+2", "+3/4d6"]
// a program can manage the "+" or "-" on the second one (usually is always an addiction)
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**, 147 symbols, no eval:

```
preg_match('/(\d+)?d(\d+)[\s+]?([\+\*])?[\s+]?(\d+)?/',$i,$a);$d=rand(1,$a[2])*((!$a[1])?1:$a[1]);$e['+']=$d+$a[4];$e['*']=$d*$a[4];print$e[$a[3]];
```

`$i` contains input string.

Edit: oops, forgot about prefixed operation. brb.